# ambiguity in mathematical meaning of "for some".

Tags: linear-transformations, quantifiers

As per my understanding "for some" means a few elements of. It refers that the statement is true for at least one element but needn't be true for all.

In the [book](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.135792/page/n6/mode/1up)   "An Introduction To Linear Algebra" by Arora, J. L on page 118 (question 3 of problem set 4.2) , "for some" is interpreted as "for all" since that is only when the statement is true.

[image: question from book]

Is this simply a case of confusing use of the phrase or this how "for some" is to be interpreted?

Comment: "for some" usually is symbolized with the [Existential quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) that means "which is interpreted as "there exists", "there is at least one", or "for some"." It does **not** mean "only some".

Comment: The definition reads: let $T(U)$ the set of the elements $w$ of $W$ such that there is (at least one) $u$ in $U$ for which: $w=T(u)$.

Comment: I don't see a problem here: it is just the definition of the image of a subset under a map, basically the image of a set $X$ under a map $f$, ie, $f(X)$ means the set $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ which can alternately be written as $\{y\mid\exists x\in X~\colon~y=f(x)\}$, ie, the set contains the elements of the codomain which have at least one preimage in $X$ under $f$

Comment: thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be phrased as "Define $T(u)$ to be the collection of all $w \in W$ for which there exists at least one $u \in U$ such that $w = T(u)$". The statement overall is "show that the image of a subspace under a linear map is a subspace", which is true.